# I would like some guidance on sizing toolbars on hi res screens

Tags: delphi

I want to change the size of my toolbars at run time and to accommodate different screen resolutions.

My toolbars are on a TControlBar, with Toolbars and ControlBar set to autosize. I have 4 differently sized TImagelists 16*16 through to 48*48 which I can I assign to the toolbars.  What I am finding is that the controlbar and toolbars increase in height when I assign a larger Imagelist but do not shrink back down when I choose a smaller imagelist.  I have also found that the toolbars do not expand in length to accommodate the wider images. Is this expected behaviour?

I have also found that at design time my largest imagelist 48*48 has actually loaded the 32*32 images.  All images are coming from a set of Icons which hold images from 64*64, 48*48 ... down to 16*16. Is there a limit to size of images an image list can store.  Each image list  holds 36 images.

```
procedure TfmIDEMain.SetIconSize(Large: Boolean);
begin
  if Large then
    case screen.PixelsPerInch of
    96..111:  ilTBIcons := ilMedIcons;          // Large Icons - Low res
    112..120: ilTBIcons := ilLargeIcons;        // Large Icons - Hi Med 
    121..144: ilTBIcons := ilExLargeIcons;      // Large Icons - hi res 
    end
  else
    case screen.PixelsPerInch of
    96..111:  ilTBIcons := ilSmallIcons;        // Small Icons - Low res
    112..120: ilTBIcons := ilMedIcons;          // Small Icons - Med res
    121..144: ilTBIcons := ilLargeIcons;        // Small Icons - hi res
    end;

  tbFiles.Images := ilTBIcons;
  tbEdit.Images := ilTBIcons;
  tbBookmarks.Images := ilTBIcons;
  tbCodeFolding.Images := ilTBIcons;
end;
```

The above routine assigns the images according to the screen resolution and the "Large" boolean. Is there anything else I should be doing to get the toolbars and control bar to resize down to the small image size?

Comment: It might help to specify your Delphi version.

Comment: I am using Delphi Berlin 10.1

Comment: Do you handle the DPI switch manually or do you let the VCL do it automatically? When do you call SetIconSize?

Comment: Its called manually when user chooses a larger/smaller image size from a menu.  Its also called from Create when initially setting up the app,

Answer (score 0):

As you already found yourself, the *ToolBar* and *ControlBar* adjust themselves to the *Imagelist* size if they don't fit already. That is why they don't shrink when assigning smaller a *Imagelist*. Even the *Toolbar* should adjust its width when you trigger an *AutoSize* by setting it to *False* and *True*.

This reaction on the *Imagelist* size has an impact on the *ScaleBy* functionality which is used when the control reacts on DPI changes. Assigning a larger *Imagelist* will enlarge the *Toolbar* and the following ScaleBy will use the wrong base sizes. The other way round when the DPI decreases the *Toolbar* cannot reduce its size accordingly as long as the large *Imagelist* is still assigned.

This requires to assign the *Imagelist* in the right order:

- a larger *Imagelist* must be assigned after scaling the control to a bigger size
- a smaller *Imagelist* must be assigned before scaling the control to a smaller size

Comment: The DPI is determined when the application is started, I am not trying to change DPI while the application is running only the size of the toolbar images.  What do you mean by scaling the control to a smaller size?  I have tried resetting the button Height and Control height to a smaller height before assigning the smaller imagelist but that didnt work.

Comment: I have also tried toggling Autosize on and off but the toolbars are not adjusting their width to accommodate the changed image sizes.

Comment: As I said: when you want to make the toolbar smaller, you must assign the smaller images first and then adjust the toolbar size manually. There is no automatism.